# Why do I get "NoneType' object has no attribute ...?

Tags: python, python-3.x

The class I have:

```
class UserInfo:

    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name
        self.prop = list([10])    # Default info

    def add_info(self, newprop):
        self.prop = [] #Create a new empty list (deletes default)
        self.prop.append(newprop)
```

The following code works good:

```
# Testing code:
 Mat2 = UserInfo('MaterialNew')

 Mat2.add_info(123)

 print("This is when a new prop is added. The prop is: {}".format(Mat2.prop))
```

But the following returns the error `'NoneType' object has no attribute 'prop'`:

```
Mat2_info = UserInfo('MaterialNew').add_info(123).prop #supposed new material info
print("This is supposed to be the new info, but it fails: {}".format(Mat2_info))
```

Can someone explain the logic?

Comment: Why is that unexpected? `add_info` doesn't *return* anything. Also I don't really see the point of `prop` being a list if it only ever contains one thing.

Comment: As described above, your `add_info` works similarly to `list.append`. It mutates the object **in-place** and returns `None`

Comment: I see it. It doesn't return anything, it just changes `Mat2`.  Wow, thank you so much!

Comment: Also, `list([10])` is the same as `[10]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are close! You are trying to do method chaining as a way to shortcut

```
tmp = UserInfo('MaterialNew').add_info(123)
Mat2_info = tmp.prop #supposed new material info
```

Just return `self` from `add_info` and it will work

```
class UserInfo:

    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name
        self.prop = list([10])    # Default info

    def add_info(self, newprop):
        self.prop = [] #Create a new empty list (deletes default)
        self.prop.append(newprop)
        return self
```

Comment: Wow! Thank you so much! This exactly what I wanted to do. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Your code is failing at the .prop part, because 'prop' != 'self.prop'.

That being said, what are you trying to accomplish with '.prop' at the end of that statement? Try removing that part.

Your first part works because you are accessing that function correctly, and not self.prop.

Comment: The code actually fails because add_info doesnt rerutn anythinng so by default `None` is returned which means they go on to call prop on `None` which would be like doing `None.prop` which will of course return the attribute error

Comment: Okay I see what you are saying, that makes sense. For some reason his question confused me a bit. I guess I misunderstood what he was expecting.